# Output file of size zero

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I am running a Hadoop mapreduce streaming job (mappers only job). In some cases my job writes to stdout whereupon an output file with non-zero size is created. In some cases my job does not write anything to stdout but still an output file of size zero is created. Is there a way to avoid creation of this file of size zero when nothing is written to stdout.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind extending your current output format, you just need to override the OutputCommitter to 'abort' the commitTask stage when no data was written.

Note that not all output formats show zero file bytes for an empty file (sequence files for example have a header), so you can't just check the output file size.

Look at the source for the following files:

- OutputCommitter - The base abstract class
- FileOutputCommitter - Most FileOutputFormats use this committer so it's a good place to start. Look into the private method `moveTaskOutputs`, this is where your logic will most likely go (to not copy the file if nothing was written)

Answer (score 0):

Are you using [MultipleOutputs](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.6.1/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/output/MultipleOutputs.html)?
If yes, MultipleOutputs creates defaults files even if the reducer has nothing to write to the output.
To avoid this default zero-sized output, you can use [LazyOutputFormat.setOutputFormatClass()](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.6.1/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/output/LazyOutputFormat.html#setOutputFormatClass(org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job,%20java.lang.Class))

From my experience, even if you are using LazyOutputFormat, zero-sized files are created when: Reducer has some data to write (so output file is created) but reducer gets killed before writing the output. I believe this is a timing issue, so you might observe that only partial reducer output files are present in HDFS or you may not observe this at all.

eg. If you have 10 reducers, you might have only 'n' (n<=10) number of files and some of them have file size equal to 0 bytes.